# How to combine HOG and LBP features with openCV in a signle cascade.xml file?

Tags: opencv, feature-selection, adaboost, lbph-algorithm

opencv_traincascade  generates a cascade.xml files for only one feature(lbp or haar or hog). Is it possible to combine obtained results  into a single file? Or is there any opencv utility that could generate a combination of two different type of features?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could as they are passed to separate functions within the OpenCV API.

Comment: is there any opencv utility that could generate a combination of two different type of features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that OpenCV does not support adding multiple features into a single cascade. We would need to change the backend and allow any arbitrary number of features for a model to be trained according to : [opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/182465/is-there-any-way-to-combine-hog-and-lbp-in-a-cascadexml-file/)